# How to get arraylist from java to android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm doing an application and I need to receive an udp array from java to android and put it in a Spinner. Does anyone know how to do it?

Now, this is the code that I'm working with but I only receive a string.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how I can receive the array working from this code?

**UDPClientSocketActivity**

```
  public class UDPClientSocketActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  private TextView mTextViewReplyFromServer;
  private EditText mEditTextSendMessage;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

  mEditTextSendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_send_message);
  mTextViewReplyFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reply_from_server);

  buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_send:
             sendMessage(mEditTextSendMessage.getText().toString());
             break;
   }
}

      private void sendMessage(final String message) {

          final Handler handler = new Handler();
          Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            String stringData;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                        DatagramSocket ds = null;
                        try {
                            ds = new DatagramSocket();
                            // IP Address below is the IP address of that Device where server socket is opened.
                           InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
                           DatagramPacket dp;
                           dp = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.length(), serverAddr, 9001);
                           ds.send(dp);

                           byte[] lMsg = new byte[1000];
                           dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
                           ds.receive(dp);
                           stringData = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ds != null) {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }

          handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String s = mTextViewReplyFromServer.getText().toString();
                if (stringData.trim().length() != 0)
                    mTextViewReplyFromServer.setText(s + "\nFrom Server : " + stringData);

             }
         });
     }
 });
          thread.start();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put data into Spinner there is a link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner